# Deploying a Spring application in a Tomcat server instance

Tags: eclipse, deployment, tomcat, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am a newbie and I want to deploy a Spring project which I get via SVN to my Tomcat application server. I did a checkout in Eclipse (Subclipse) and so the project is located in my workspace.

I downloaded the 6.0.29 Tomcat server and extracted it to a directory. Then I create a new Tomcat server in the Server tab of Eclipse. I can start it and I see the Tomcat start page at hrttp://localhost:8080/

But how can I deploy the Spring application, so that it will run in my Tomcat server?

Here is a screenshot of my IDE and the Server settings:

http://img828.imageshack.us/img828/8711/screenshotku.png

Thanks a lot in advance for your hel and Best Regards.

Comment: Are you looking to deploy your application through Eclipse? If so, you'll likely need an Ant script to do so, which is also an Apache product.

Comment: Now I am using Maven2, and it seems to be okay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But how can I deploy the Spring application, so that it will run in my Tomcat server?

Your project needs to be a **Dynamic Web Project** (or to be recognized as such) and I don't think that the one in your workspace currently is (you are supposed to import the content of `trunk`, not the directory above). Actually, I'd suggest to perform the checkout like this:

```
svn co https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-basic/trunk/ mvc-basic
```

And then to import the `mvc-basic` directory inside Eclipse with **Import... > General > Existing Project into Workspace**.